# My MetaMask account was compromised, but I don't know how

Tags: ether, metamask, security

On Feb 2, 2022, a hacker drained ~$500.00 of ETH from my account which I set up with MetaMask. You can see the transaction here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xde505c5d1897d6101fc442e5ae093814b5c3fe0f

I'm mostly over the fact that I lost money, it just bothers me that I don't know *how* it happened in the first place. The thing is, I never fell for any scam, e.g. "give us your seed phrase for technical support" or something stupid like that. I double checked that the wallet app on my phone and browser both came from a legitimate source and nothing seemed out of place.

I probably could've been a little more careful with my seed phrase, I stored it in a document in Google Drive which might have been my fatal flaw. But what doesn't make sense is that I had seed phrases for other accounts in there and none of them were compromised (I have since deleted that document and transferred the crypto out anyway). The only other places that my seed phrases were stored was on paper in my room and I highly doubt someone broke into my apartment building just to steal my crypto.

I may have copied and pasted the seed phrase once or twice when setting up my account, but I've run a virus scan on my computer and phone and there was no evidence of any keylogger or malware that scans your clipboard for seed phrases. Is it possible that a website open in your browser could see what's in your clipboard? I often have many Chrome tabs open at once and I wonder if that could've been what got me.

I checked this website, https://tac.dappstar.io/#/, for if I gave anyone "unlimited approval" over my account, but it came up negative. At this point, I'm just looking for more ideas as to what happened and how I could prevent it in the future, otherwise I'm just going to continue believing that using any self-managed wallet is unsafe.

[image: Transaction details]

One more thing, for some reason, the transaction only shows up on my phone and not the Chrome extension on my desktop PC. Does that mean the fraudulent transaction was initiated from my phone? Is it possible that there's a vulnerability in the Android app for MetaMask? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What do you mean by "I may have copied and pasted the seed phrase once or twice when setting up my account"? Where exactly have you pasted it? Which websites did you use?

Comment: @KenzoAgada I believe I copied it when I was setting up MetaMask on my laptop and phone. I would never just copy it into some random website.

Comment: You don't need to copy-paste seed phrase. Any generic malware / virus you get from installing illegal software or EXE files will steal crypto as well.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa But I scanned for viruses and didn't find anything

Comment: Anti-virus software is not reliable. The only way to avoid computer viruses is not to install random software from Internet.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Now that you mention it, there are a couple of questionable programs which I installed. So, in the future I should just assume that any program I install can see what I copy/paste and read any files I have saved on my PC? That's a little ridiculous.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly how it happens.